# Confusion about the Kronecker $\delta$

Tags: kronecker-symbol

Something disturbs me, concerning the Kronecker $\delta$.

Assuming these hold: $$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$$ $$\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ji}$$ $$\delta_{ii}=1$$ does it follow that for every  $\delta_{ij}$ we have $(\delta_{ij})^2=\delta_{ij}\delta_{ji}=\delta_{ii}=1$?

This makes no sense, as $\delta_{ij}$ can also be equal $0$.

Can anyone clear the confusion?

---

Edit: I am using Einstein notation. Do Kronecker deltas in Einstein notation always equal something different then zero? For example, if $\delta_{ii}=n$, does it imply $\delta_{ij}=n^{0.5}$ for all $\delta_{ij}$?

Comment: Are you using the Einstein summation convention?  The first equation you list is only true if you are using it.  The third equation is only true if you're not (or if your index set only has one element).

Comment: It seems that the author is using Einstein notation

Comment: Given two matrices $A$ and $B$, $A_{ij}$ is one entry of $A$ and $B_{jk}$ is another entry of $B$.  Matrix multiplication is defined entrywise as $$[AB]_{ik} = \sum_j A_{ij}B_{jk}$$  But using the Einstein summation convention, the RHS can just be written $A_{ij}B_{jk}$ where we see that we're supposed to sum over $j$ because there are two of them.  If you see an expression like $A_{ii}$ then you need to realize that this is NOT one entry of $A$ -- this has an implied summation as well (over $i$).  $A_{ii}= A_{11} + A_{22} + \cdots + A_{nn} = \operatorname{trace}(A)$.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you for a good comment. So, how do I know which meaning does the notation have when I see it?

Comment: If there are any repeated indices then a summation is implied.  Otherwise there is no summation implied.  So $A_{ij}$ is one entry of $A$ because there are no repeated indices but $A_{ii} = \sum_i A_{ii}$ because $i$ is a repeated index.

Comment: @Bye_World But if I do want to refer to the regular form of the Kronecker delta ($\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$, $0$ else), how do I make sure it won't be understood as in the summation?

Comment: Well if you put repeated indices anywhere in a term -- for instance $\delta_{ij}v_i$ has a repeated $i$ -- then readers will assume that you mean to imply summation over the $i$ UNLESS you write something like "summation not implied" afterward.

Comment: @Bye_World I see. So the Einstein notation is the "defualt", unless said otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: @Whyka: One thing I will say as a warning is that whether or not people assume S.C. is being used can depend on context. As a rule of thumb, applied mathematicians and physicists will assume it's being used; but pure mathematicians will commonly state clearly if it is being used, and otherwise will not use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're confused about this notation, most likely because of what I suspect is the inconsistent use of **summation convention**.

The first statement is only correct if implicitly summed over $j$:
$$\sum_j \delta_{ij}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$$

The last statement however is only true if there is no summation over $i$, since generically if $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ then
$$\sum_i \delta_{ii} = n$$

This inconsistency is what is causing you problems.

(Notice for example that if $n=1$ then there is no such ambiguity **but** indeed it is not possible for $\delta_{ij}$ to be anything other than 1!)

---

**Edit in response to comment**: To respond to your comment, no. $\delta_{ij}$ takes different values depending on what $i,j$ are. For example in 3D,
$$\delta_{ij} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}_{ij}$$
Hence using summation convention, e.g. $\delta_{ii} \equiv \delta_{11} + \delta_{22} + \delta_{33} = 3$

Generally, $\delta_{ij}$ is just a thing that tells you whether or not $i = j$. If yes, then it is 1, if no, then it is 0. You can also think of these as the components of the identity matrix as suggested in the comments by Bye_World.

Comment: So, if I use Einstein notation, then $\delta_{ij}$ always equals $3^{0.5}$ in 3-D?

Comment: Maybe it would help you to understand the $\delta_{ij}$ just means the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column of the **identity matrix**.  So of course $\delta_{ij}\ne 3^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Whyka: I've responded in the question because it's much easier that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So why does it make sense that if n=1 $\delta_{ij}=1$ always?

Comment: Because we are looking at an 1*1 matrix?

Comment: @Whyka Exactly! Another way to look at it is that if $i,j\in \{1\}$ then $i=j$ always!

Comment: @Sharkos it is all clearer now. Thanks a lot!